# Matrix with maximal rank in a family of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the family of $n \times n$ real matrices $A$, for which there is a $n \times n$ real matrix $B$ with $AB-BA=A$. How large can the rank of a matrix in this family be?

### Motivation

Prasolov's book contains an exercise about proving that if $A,B$ are matrices with $AB-BA=A$ then $A$ cannot be invertible. (It is easy to prove this by multiplying both sides of the equation by $A^{-1}$ assuming it exists and then taking trace.)

I tried to come up with concrete examples of such matrices $A,B$ with $A$ having as large a rank as possible. By restricting $B$ to diagonal matrices one comes up with a very simple criterion and it is easy to construct matrices with rank $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$. For example for $ n = 4$ and for $ad - bc \neq 0$ we have
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & c & d \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: It is notable that you're analyzing the solutions of the [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) $AX - XA = A$.

Comment: Note that this equation will never have a unique solution.  In particular: suppose that $AC  = CA$ and that $AB - BA = A$, then we must also have $A(B+C) - (B+C)A = A$.

Comment: The claim that $A$ must be singular is true only because the field $\mathbb R$ has characteristic zero. If the underlying field has an appropriate finite characteristic, the claim may not hold. E.g. over $GF(2)$ (where $1+1=0$), we have $AB-BA=A$ when
$$A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1},\ B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a solution of rank $n-1$. An example that (if I recall correctly) has appeared on this site is $A$ being the $n\times n$ upper triangular nilpotent Jordan block and $B=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,\ldots,n)$.

Answer (score 2):

With $n=3$, you can get rank 2, e.g., $$A=\pmatrix{0&1&1\cr0&0&1\cr0&0&0}\qquad B=\pmatrix{0&1&c\cr0&1&0\cr0&0&2\cr}$$ I would hazard a guess that one can always get rank $n-1$.